# SQL to find customers that have ordered at least once a month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to query customers that have ordered at least once a month during a specified year or over multiple years.  I don't want to divide how many orders they have and see an average of at least 12 a year.  I need to know that they actually ordered at least once in every month during that range.

What I have so far is below, but it seems like there should be a better way to do this.  Is there a better way to write this query?

```
with CustomersThatOrderAtLeastOnceAMonth as (
    select c.username, c.id
    from customer c
    where exists (select 1 from orders o where c.id = o.CustomerId and o.orderdate between '2015-01-01' and '2015-02-01')   
      and exists (select 1 from orders o where c.id = o.CustomerId and o.orderdate between '2015-02-01' and '2015-03-01')   
      and exists (select 1 from orders o where c.id = o.CustomerId and o.orderdate between '2015-03-01' and '2015-04-01')   
      and exists (select 1 from orders o where c.id = o.CustomerId and o.orderdate between '2015-04-01' and '2015-05-01')   
      and exists (select 1 from orders o where c.id = o.CustomerId and o.orderdate between '2015-05-01' and '2015-06-01')   
      and exists (select 1 from orders o where c.id = o.CustomerId and o.orderdate between '2015-06-01' and '2015-07-01')   
      and exists (select 1 from orders o where c.id = o.CustomerId and o.orderdate between '2015-07-01' and '2015-08-01')   
      and exists (select 1 from orders o where c.id = o.CustomerId and o.orderdate between '2015-08-01' and '2015-09-01')   
      and exists (select 1 from orders o where c.id = o.CustomerId and o.orderdate between '2015-09-01' and '2015-10-01')   
      and exists (select 1 from orders o where c.id = o.CustomerId and o.orderdate between '2015-10-01' and '2015-11-01')   
      and exists (select 1 from orders o where c.id = o.CustomerId and o.orderdate between '2015-11-01' and '2015-12-01')   
      and exists (select 1 from orders o where c.id = o.CustomerId and o.orderdate between '2015-12-01' and '2016-01-01')   
)
```

Comment: why not just use  `between '2015-01-01' and '2016-01-01'` ?

Comment: do you have a dates table to join on? otherwise how would you account for months when there were no orders?

Comment: Using between only tells me if they've ordered during that time.  I could then query how many orders during that time.  However, they could have ordered 12 times in January and no other month.  I need to know that they ordered in each and every month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
select customerid
from orders o
where o.orderdate >= '2015-01-01' and o.orderdate < '2016-01-01' 
group by customerid
having count(distinct year(orderdate)*100 + month(orderdate)) = 12;
```

If you have an index on `orders(customerid, orderdate)`, I'm not sure if this is faster.  It might depend on the distribution of the data.  Clearly, if you had 1,000,000 customers and only 1 ordered in all months and that was the only order in January, then your code would probably be faster.

Comment: This will work for one year of a range which is my example.  I further modified it to work with any date range like this:

select customerid
from orders o
where o.orderdate >= '2015-01-01' and o.orderdate < '2017-05-01' 
group by customerid
having count(distinct year(orderdate)*100 + month(orderdate)) = datediff(month, '2015-01-01', '2017-05-01');

Comment: As a follow up question, how would I check to see if they have ordered at least once a quarter?

Comment: @BenAnderson . . . You can replace `month()` with `datepart(quarter, . . .)` and `12` with 4.